# Chart Label text rotation

Tags: html, canvas, graph, html5-canvas

I am using very similar code to create a pie chart using canvas as per this article:

http://wickedlysmart.com/how-to-make-a-pie-chart-with-html5s-canvas/

As you can see from this image, there are cases where the labels are upside down:

[image]

Here is the code that writes the labels to the graph:

```
var drawSegmentLabel = function(canvas, context, i) {

        context.save();
        var x = Math.floor(canvas.width / 2);
        var y = Math.floor(canvas.height / 2);
        var degrees = sumTo(data, i);

        var angle = degreesToRadians(degrees);

        context.translate(x, y);
        context.rotate(angle);
        context.textAlign = 'right';
        var fontSize = Math.floor(canvas.height / 32);
        context.font = fontSize + 'pt Helvetica';

        var dx = Math.floor(canvas.width * 0.3) - 20;
        var dy = Math.floor(canvas.height * 0.05);
        context.fillText(labels[i], dx, dy);

        context.restore();
```

};

I am trying to rectify this so the text is always readable and not upside down but cant work out how to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution! (A little kludgey but seems to work on the basic example, I haven't tested in on edge cases...)

```
var drawSegmentLabel = function(canvas, context, i) {

    context.save();
    var x = Math.floor(canvas.width / 2);
    var y = Math.floor(canvas.height / 2);
    var angle;
    var angleD = sumTo(data, i);
    var flip = (angleD < 90 || angleD > 270) ? false : true;

    context.translate(x, y);
    if (flip) {
        angleD = angleD-180;
        context.textAlign = "left";
        angle = degreesToRadians(angleD);
        context.rotate(angle);
        context.translate(-(x + (canvas.width * 0.5))+15, -(canvas.height * 0.05)-10);
    }
    else {
        context.textAlign = "right";
        angle = degreesToRadians(angleD);
        context.rotate(angle);
    }
    var fontSize = Math.floor(canvas.height / 25);
    context.font = fontSize + "pt Helvetica";

    var dx = Math.floor(canvas.width * 0.5) - 10;
    var dy = Math.floor(canvas.height * 0.05);
    context.fillText(labels[i], dx, dy);

    context.restore();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the text in the correct way you have to check if the rotation angle is between 90 and 270 degree. If it is then you know the text will be display upside down.

To switch it correctly you then have to rotate you canvas of planed rotation - 180 degree and then to align it in left not right :

```
var drawSegmentLabel = function(canvas, context, i) {

    context.save();
    var x = Math.floor(canvas.width / 2);
    var y = Math.floor(canvas.height / 2);
    var degrees = sumTo(data, i);

    var angle = 0;
    if (degree > 90 && degree < 270)
      angle = degreesToRadians(degrees - 180);       
     else
       angle = degreesToRadians(degrees);

    context.translate(x, y);
    context.rotate(angle);
    context.textAlign = 'right';
    var fontSize = Math.floor(canvas.height / 32);
    context.font = fontSize + 'pt Helvetica';

    var dx = Math.floor(canvas.width * 0.3) - 20;
    if (degree > 90 && degree < 270)
       dx =  20;
    var dy = Math.floor(canvas.height * 0.05);
    context.fillText(labels[i], dx, dy);

    context.restore();
};
```

Comment: This isnt correct - my original code: http://imgur.com/5N6mj4C 
your code: http://imgur.com/iawX3iu . The label is the correct way up, but now isnt on the correct segment